# Using JAVA array or list to fill text boxes on a page designed by Selenium Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium

```
package com.objects;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import com.tests.BaseClass;

public class LinkedInHomePage extends BaseClass {

public LinkedInHomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "firstName-coldRegistrationForm")
public WebElement newFirstNameTexthBox;

@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "lastName")
public WebElement newLastNameTexthBox;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "email-coldRegistrationForm")
public WebElement newEmailTexthBox;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "password-coldRegistrationForm")
public WebElement newPasswordTexthBox;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "btn-submit")
public WebElement signUpButton;

public void EnterNewFirstName(String inComingNewFirstName) {
    newFirstNameTexthBox.clear();
    newFirstNameTexthBox.sendKeys(inComingNewFirstName);
}

public void EnterNewLastName(String inComingNewLastName) {
    newLastNameTexthBox.clear();
    newLastNameTexthBox.sendKeys(inComingNewLastName);
}

public void EnterNewEmail(String inComingNewEmail) {
    newEmailTexthBox.clear();
    newEmailTexthBox.sendKeys(inComingNewEmail);
}

public void EnterNewPassword(String inComingNewPassword) {
    newPasswordTexthBox.clear();
    newPasswordTexthBox.sendKeys(inComingNewPassword);
}

public void ClickSignUp() {
    signUpButton.click();
}

public void JoinNow(String FName, String LName, String Email,
        String Password) {
    EnterNewFirstName(FName);
    EnterNewLastName(LName);
    EnterNewEmail(Email);
    EnterNewPassword(Password);
    ClickSignUp();
}
```

}

The JoinNow() function above as you can see takes multiple parameters and it works perfectly fine. I would like use array or list to reduce
the number of arguments and then use loop to fill the text boxes. I want to accomplish something similar as below, but since I am using Page Object Model Design, can't use findElement.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void JoinNow(String... var) {
    List<MyElements> inputElements = new ArrayList<MyElements>();
    inputElements.add((MyElements) driver.findElement(By
            .id("firstName-coldRegistrationForm")));
    inputElements.add((MyElements) driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")));
    inputElements.add((MyElements) driver.findElement(By
            .id("email-coldRegistrationForm")));
    inputElements.add((MyElements) driver.findElement(By
            .id("password-coldRegistrationForm")));

    for (int i = 0; i < var.length; i++) {
        ((WebElement) inputElements.get(i)).sendKeys(var[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused where the 2nd segment of code "protected void JoinNow" is located. Where is the reference to driver coming from?

Comment: The 2nd JoinNow(String... var) is just something I was using before implementing Page Object Model Design & now no longer in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not send a `Map` to `JoinNow` method. I suggest you keep your PageObject pattern as is. I believe this is more readable and more maintainable long term

```
Map<String,String> data  = new HashMap<String,String>();
data.put("firstname", "George");
data.put("lastname", "Clooney");
data.put("email", "George@xyz.com");
data.put("password", "Dontguess");
JoinNow(data);

protected void JoinNow(Map<String,String> data) {
    firstNameElement.sendKeys(data.get("firstname"));
    lastNameElement.sendKeys(data.get("lastname"));
    emailElement.sendKeys(data.get("email"));
    passwordElement.sendKeys(data.get("password"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please show me how can I declare map variable & call the JoinNow function?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of items you need to consider while doing page object model. Based on how you have done it (by using @FindBy), sometimes you will end up with stale data. For better results you should be defining your ids like below and use them to get you Webelemment. This is how i would design it. Define all your By.id and put it into a list and use the function below to simplify it.

**Definition of by:**
`static final By FNAME_REGFORM_BY_ID = By.id("firstName-coldRegistrationForm");`

```
public void fillTextBoxes(List<By> bys, List<String> valuesToPopulate) {
    List<WebElement> webelements = new ChromeDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type=text]"));
    for (int i = 0; i < bys.size(); i++) {
        new ChromeDriver().findElement(bys.get(i)).sendKeys(valuesToPopulate.get(i));
    }
}
```

**Edit**: For better understanding, fillTextBoxes was equivalent of joinNow.

```
List<String> values=new LiskedList<String>();
Values.add("emailid");
values.add("firstname");

List<By> bys=new LinkedList<By>();
bys.add(FNAME_REGFORM_BY_ID);
bys.add(EMAIL_ID_By_ID);

public void joinNow(List<By> bys, List<String> values) {
    List<WebElement> webelements = new ChromeDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type=text]"));
    for (int i = 0; i < bys.size(); i++) {
        new ChromeDriver().findElement(bys.get(i)).sendKeys(valuesToPopulate.get(i));
    }
}
```

Don't use Annotated @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "email-coldRegistrationForm") etc, as this slow down execution as well as gives you stale data. **FindBy** tends to slow down as the entire page object becomes completely initialized only after all elements are available. Try using Static By like i mentioned. We ran into perf issues and started switching from annotated Findby.

Based on request, here is a sample implementation. You might have to tweak based on your project requirements, but this should get started.

Your Page Class (renamed as SO for my sake).

```
public class SO {

    WebDriver driver;

    static final By FNAME_REGFORM_BY_ID = By.id("firstName-coldRegistrationForm");
    static final By LNAME_REGFORM_BY_NAME = By.className("lastName");
    static final By EMAIL_REGFORM_BY_ID = By.id("email-coldRegistrationForm");
    static final By PWD_REGFORM_BY_ID = By.id("password-coldRegistrationForm");
    static final By SUBMIT_REGFORM_BY_ID = By.id("btn-submit");

    public SO(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public List<By> getAllInput() {
        List<By> bys = new LinkedList<By>();
        bys.add(FNAME_REGFORM_BY_ID);
        bys.add(LNAME_REGFORM_BY_NAME);
        bys.add(LNAME_REGFORM_BY_NAME);
        bys.add(LNAME_REGFORM_BY_NAME);
        bys.add(LNAME_REGFORM_BY_NAME);
        return bys;
    }

    public void joinNow(List<String> values) {
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, HotelDetailsPage.class);
        List<By> bys = this.getAllInput();
        List<WebElement> webElements = this.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type=text]"));
        for (int i = 0; i < bys.size(); i++) {
            new ChromeDriver().findElement(bys.get(i)).sendKeys(values.get(i));
        }
    }

    public SO open(final String url) {
        this.driver.get(url);
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Test Method:**

```
   @Test
public void testForm() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    SO so = new SO(driver);
    SO soPage = so.open("your app url");

    List<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();
    values.add("firstname");
    values.add("lastName");
    values.add("emailId");
    values.add("password");
    values.add("id");
    soPage.joinNow(values);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me how can I call the JoinNow function from test class using parameter: (List<By> bys, List<String> valuesToPopulate)

Comment: @ minion, can you show me how to call joinNow(List<By> bys, List<String> values) method from TestClass? Also, I am using firefox driver not chrome. I will appreciate if you can show me the full Testclass, full POM class & full base class.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the another way:

```
HashMap<WebElement, String> d = new HashMap<WebElement, String>();
d.put(newFirstNameTexthBox, "Michael");
d.put(newLastNameTexthBox, "Johnson");
d.put(newEmailTexthBox, "a@b.com");
d.put(newPasswordTexthBox, "Michael123$");
joinNow(d); 


protected void JoinNow(Map<WebElement,String> data) {
    for (Entry<WebElement, String> objValue : data.entrySet())
        objValue.getKey().sendKeys(objValue.getValue());
}
```